# Correlation with a highly significant P value and a low Pearson (r) value

Tags: regression, correlation, pearson-r

I am working on patients data (168614). I examined the correlation between blood test (HbA1c) and average weekly max temperature. I found a highly significant correlation but low Pearson (r) value (as in the photo):
[image: Correlation result]

Now, is it true to report this result (finding) and apply further analysis such as regression? Or not!!

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93757/pearson-correlation-coefficient-test-low-r-and-low-p-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've found small correlation between two variables, but the effect is highly significant, congratulations! This means you are working with a lot of patients and very powerful (i.e: likely to detect true effects) tests, as all reserach should be done!

I don't have too much knowledge about the exact hypothesis you are testing, but it seems that your target variable has a lot of "randomness", with the effect of your predictor being small, but consistent. If possible, you may want to work with a more complex model, using more independent predictors

Comment: Thank you so much, David, for your useful comments and I really appreciate that for you. My hypothesis is high weather temperature can increase HbA1c (blood test of diabetes).

Comment: OK, so I guess the conclusion is that HbA1c levels are definitely higher at high temperatures. If you want to quantify by how much on average, you may want to fit a linear regression model and check the coefficients. However, there are many other factors that also play a role in HbA1c levels

Comment: Thank you very much David. I'll try to fit linear regression and I'll use more factors such as age and gender.

Answer (score 2):

You ask two questions:

> Now, is it true to report this result (finding)

It is fine to report any result, significant or not, large or not, as long as you are honest about what you are reporting.

> Apply further analysis such as regression? Or not!!

This sounds like you are doing bivariate screening for regression. This is a bad idea (although it is commonly done) regardless of the effect size and the significance.

Comment: Thank you so much, Peter, for your useful comments. I would appreciate if you can recommend the best alternative for the bivariate screening for regression, please Peter.